# ABPersonRef - usage

Tags: iphone

Trying to create a object for ABPersonRef 
example:
ABpersonRef ref;

have included Addressbook and AddressBookUI framework 
even then when i compile it states 'ABPersonRef' Undeclared Identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added imports to your source file?

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

**Edit:** I've read your question more carefully. There's no ABPersonRef type (at least public) in iPhone SDK. You should work with ABRecordRef type which is generic for both person and group records - as you can see all AB*** methods work with ABRecordRef type.

Comment: have included both the headers

Comment: for making use of ABPersonCopyVCardRepresentation need to create a object for ABPersonRef but it is getting linked to the workspace

Comment: wanted to make use of ABPerson i have included both the AddressBook headers

Comment: it seems ABPersonCopyVCardRepresentation is also not a part of iPhone SDK, it is available on MacOS only (as well as ABPersonRef)

Comment: can u tell me how to create a vcard in iphone programatically

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to link against AddressBook framework and

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

Comment: i have included both the headers